# printf format f versus d in Python

Tags: python, c, printf

Some `C` code I am working in has an `int` set to -145. Depending on the format, the value returns as either `0.00` or `-145`. Take the following

```
int a = -145;

printf("%.2lf", a); // returns 0.00
printf("%.2ld", a); // returns -145
```

First question is how is it that the first line is returning `0.00`? Second question is how to return `0.00` in Python?

Among the many iterations I've tried, here are a few:

```
a = -145

"%0.2lf" % a # -145.00
"%0.2ld" % a # -145
"%0.2li" % a # -145
"%0.2f" % a # -145.00
```

Comment: Of course @ouah is correct:  C defines nothing about what happens in the code you showed; it will vary across platforms, and may result in anything from displaying gibberish to crashing with a segfault.  C's `printf` family is notoriously prone to errors this way.  To answer your 2nd question, you cannot "trick" Python this way - there's no way to get Python to treat -145 as anything other than what it is:  an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 int a = -145;

printf("%.2lf", a); // returns 0.00
printf("%.2ld", a); // returns -145
```

Both function calls invoke undefined behavior. The correct conversion specifier to print an `int` is `d` not `lf` (for `double`), not `ld` (for `long`).

Answer (score 0):

> Second question is how to return `0.00` in Python?

If you insist:

```
import struct

def misinterpret_int_as_double(n):
    int_bytes = struct.pack('i', n)
    padding = b'\x00' * (struct.calcsize('d') - struct.calcsize('i'))
    return struct.unpack('d', int_bytes + padding)[0]

>>> misinterpret_int_as_double(-145)
2.1219957193e-314
```

This is essentially what your C code is doing behind the scenes.  C doesn't do any type-checking (at compile-time *or* run-time) on the arguments passed in the `...` part of a call to a varargs function.  What happens is that the memory that stores `printf`'s arguments contains:

1. A pointer to the string literal `"%.2lf`.
2. The bytes representing the number -145.  (On x86-32 or x86-64, this is the 4 bytes `91 FF FF FF`.)
3. Some garbage data.  (In the Python code above, this is assumed to be all zeros, but in your C program it need not be.)

The `printf` function sees the `lf` specifier and expects a `double`.  So, it interprets the following bytes, `91 FF FF FF xx xx xx xx` (where `xx` = garbage) as  one.  For about 1/4 of the possible values of the garbage (including `00 00 00 00`), the number is small enough to round to zero.

Note that I've assumed a bunch of stuff: That you have a little-endian system with 4-byte `int` and 8-byte `double`.  That function arguments are passed in ascending order in memory.  And that your code doesn't segfault.  YMMV on other hardware/OS/compiler combinations.  That's how it is with undefined behavior.

Python works differently, because it's safely typed.  If you pass the “wrong” type to `str`'s `%` operator, it will automatically convert the operand to the correct type by calling the magic `__float__` method (or `__str__` or `__int__` or whatever depending on which format it is).